# Should we drastically change titles on highly viewed/voted questions?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, title, specific-edit

This was the original title of a certain Q&A (link at bottom):

> Seaborn Barplot - Displaying Values

Now that's not a great title per MSO standards, but the question has been very discoverable over the last 5 years. It has 189K views (significant for this subject), and my answer has gotten 100+ votes in 1 year.

---

Another user is now trying to drastically change the title to (a) better conform to titling guidance and (b) be very specific:

> How to display different values on a barplot than those plotted

However, I don't think we should make drastic changes like this if the question has already proven successful in SEO and in being discoverable/helpful to end users.

---

IMO if we want to update the old title, we should just tweak the original wording into a conversational style, e.g.:

> How to display custom values on seaborn barplot

What does MSO think about this situation? It was starting to become an edit war, so I figured it would be better to find consensus here.

The post at hand: [stackoverflow.com/q/43214978/13138364](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43214978/13138364)

Comment: Discoverability is an tricky thing... # of views doesn't necessarily mean that it's optimised for discovery (meaning: the question easy to find for people looking for solutions on this topic _and_ not polluting the search for people looking for similar tasks) . It's hard to say how many people came across the post looking for something else. The original title seems to be an overfit (too broad and would attract viewers not looking for this thread). The new title seems much more descriptive, though I personally prefer your modified version "How to display custom values on seaborn barplot" more.

Comment: Since the highest voted answer (yours!) shows this is a fundamental task that can be solved with the basic matplotlib, I don't think restricting the title to the higher-level seaborn is appropriate.

Comment: So in terms of SEO, the main change to the title is removal of the tag "[Seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/seaborn/info)"(?).

Comment: Are you sure the majority of the views are not due to false positive hits from search engines (despite the specificity provided by using "Seaborn" in the title)? Seaborn seems relatively obscure. One data point is that I have never encountered Seaborn until today. 0.4% of Python question are tagged with Seaborn.

Comment: Yes, if something is bad then you are free to improve. The only question if it is really an improvement. The system trusts you in this decision from rep 2000, so you can edit any posts as you wish to. However, this is also a huge reponsibility. | If you can improve, then improve. If the post is highly visited/voted, you have yet more strong reason to improve.

Comment: [Should I use tags in titles?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tagging#:~:text=Should%20I%20use%20tags%20in,they%20follow%20or%20search%20for.), specifically states not to tag in the title. Additionally, `.bar_label` is a matplotlib method, which seaborn can use. seaborn should not be in the title because all of the answers work for matplotlib, and pandas bar plots too. There's nothing in the question _**how I use a value that is not in the graph as the basis for the label**_ (i.e. these are the exact words of the OP), or answers that is specific to seaborn.

Comment: If this title, _**Seaborn Barplot - Displaying Values**_, reflected the actual question, then this would already be [closed as a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/43214978/timeline#history_f5c33d30-c93c-4829-a1e2-2cc776eb8cef), and as stated in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43214978/how-to-display-different-values-on-a-barplot-than-those-plotted#comment128816068_43214978). I don't update titles as vandalism, they are updated to cohesively reflect the question being asked, and then relevant technologies are tagged.

Comment: As you suggest, I think _**How to display custom values on a barplot**_ is a better title because it more succinctly coveys the issue. However, it should not include the seaborn tag, which is in the tags, and suggests the question is only relevant to seaborn, which it's not.

Comment: _**my answer has gotten 100+ votes in 1 year**_ is true, however your answer doesn't actually answer the question in the OP, which is the issue. You answered the title, not the question asked by the OP. You posted an answer to a question that is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28931224/7758804) of an older more, viewed question, and the **Color-ranked version** section of the answer is a rehash of what's covered in the accepted answer, and was added a month later as an edit. More accurate titles prevent this type of mistake, and correctly inform others of the intent of the OP.

Comment: I would change the title of this question to: **Should the titles of popular questions be changed?** 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found that prioritizing curation is the best way to approach it. Do what's best for the question *while* you weigh potential search implications. But in reality, they [the implications] really are potential, and the concern is "something in the black box might change."

But we *know* the question would be objectively more helpful if we edit it, and search engines have never really struggled to discover content changes so my advice is keep thinking like you do, but don't index too much for the black boxes.

Comment: Though, it would be interesting to see how pages that had drastic title edits scored in indexes VS the SEO scraped copies that actually follow the rules so they tend to rank, but almost never sync edits from the time they got the content out of the DB dump or new question feed. 

If you had enough of them identified you could actually look at this with some kind of effective lens to see what kind of SEO effects it has, if any.

Comment: You could use anonymous feedback for that.